# Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_tools ubuntu

Tags: flutter, ubuntu

recently I uninstall flutter from snap and tried to install it manually. but when I try to run `flutter doctor` or `flutter pub get` i face this issue.

then I reinstall flutter from the snap. but still the same issue. please help me...

[image]